# A truncated Frobenius norm of a matrix is convex or not?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, convex-analysis, norms, singular-values

Given a positive integer $k$ and a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. A truncated frobenius norm of a matrix $X$ is defined by
$$\Vert X \Vert_{k,F} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=k+1}^{m} \sigma_i^2(X)},$$
where $\sigma_i(X)$ are singular values of $X$. I wonder that this norm is convex or not?

For the case Frobenius norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_F$, I can prove it is convex by showing it is a unitarily invariant norm (since $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is gauge function). But for the case truncated Frobenius norm, I can't use the same technique because $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{k,2}$ is not a gauge function.

Comment: And here you arrange them in decreasing order: $\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2\ge\ldots$ ?

Comment: In that case you don't have convexity when $k+1=m$: $\sigma_m=0$ means that the matrix is singular, but a convex combination of two singular matrices need not be singular (won't be, typically).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, I arrange singular values in decreasing order. About your second comment, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can have $\sigma_m(A)=\sigma_m(B)=0$, $\sigma_m((A+B)/2)>0$.